# cucumber: drop down should have item selected? How with xpath? Or maybe something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, cucumber

```
<select id="search_user_id_equals_any" name="search[user_id_equals_any]">
    <option value="2">My Stuff</option>
    <option value="-1,1,2,3,4,5">All Users</option>
    <option value="3">The Cat</option>
</select>
```

So, above is the drop down I want to verify something is selected in.

Now, when you click on something, it doesn't add the selected="selected" to whatever option you click, so I don't know how to figure out the selection.

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
   find_field(search_user_id_equals_any).value.should =~ /#{your_expected_value}/
```

?

Comment: value is just the value of the attribute "value" of an option tag, isn't it? I want the text to be matched =\

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the [Capybara source](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Simple#value-instance_method) how the value method works:

```
option = native.xpath(".//option[@selected='selected']").first || native.xpath(".//option").first
option[:value] || option.content if option
```

So it looks like by design it will return the option's value, if present, and otherwise it will return the text content. And note how if no option is selected, it will default to the first, as a real browser would.

To get the behaviour you want, you could do something like this:

```
node = find_field('search_user_id_equals_any')
option = node.xpath(".//option[@selected='selected']").first || node.xpath(".//option").first
option_text = option.content
```